# Role capability delete multiple post type posts doesn't work

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities

I am making a new role called "sales" where I add capabilities to, so the sales people only can read, edit and delete leads in the admin panel.

Everything works fine, except that I cannot select multiple leads (posts) and delete them in one time. I have added the capabilities "delete_lead" and "delete_leads" so in my opinion this should work.

```
// Create sales role
add_role( 'sales', __( 'Sales', 'gtp_translate' ) );

// Add sales capabilities to sales
$roles = array( 'sales', 'editor', 'administrator' );
foreach( $roles as $the_role ) {
    // Get role object by role name
    $role = get_role( $the_role );
    // Add capabilities to this role
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_lead' );
    $role->add_cap( 'read_lead' );  
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_lead' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'publish_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'read_private_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_private_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_private_leads' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_leads' );
}
```

Normally your post type action drop down should look like the image, but "Move to trash" is not there now.

[image]

**My Leads custom post type**

```
// Leads
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Leads', 'Post Type General Name', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Lead', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Leads', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Lead:', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Leads', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Lead', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Lead', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Lead', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Lead', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Leads', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'gtp_translate' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'gtp_translate' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'leads',
    'description'         => 'Leads',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => false,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 3,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => false,
    'capability_type'     => array( 'lead', 'leads' ),
);
register_post_type( 'leads', $args );
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code responsible?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes I am sure. The only thing which maybe is relevant is that I use `'capability_type' => array( 'lead', 'leads' )` as argument for my leads post type.

Comment: hmm... at least post the code for your "Leads" CPT so the whole thing can be replicated.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Watch my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add

**map_meta_cap => true**,

in the **args** of **register_post_type**

```
    'publicly_queryable'  => false,
    'map_meta_cap'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => array( 'lead', 'leads' ),
);
register_post_type( 'leads', $args );
```